# Sharing Components with multiple containers

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jpopupmenu

I have  JTabbedPane and each tab has a JTextPane.

Each JTextPane has a popup-menu but I want all of them to share the exact same popup-menu. Why? Because when I switch tabs, I want the same options to be highlighted on each popup.

How can I do this? I tried adding a static PopupMenu instance to each pane but when I add it to one, it disappears from the others..

EDIT: In the following SSCCE, when the checkbox is checked on TabOne, it is not Checked on TabTwo. I want it Checked On BOTH tabs. All the other options can be unique to each tab except for that one.

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        final Main M = new Main();

        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame F = new JFrame("SSCCE");
                    JTabbedPane Pane = new JTabbedPane();
                    Pane.addTab("TabOne", M.new DebugBox(500, 500));
                    Pane.addTab("TabTwo", M.new DebugBox(500, 500));

                    F.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    F.add(Pane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    F.pack();
                    F.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    F.setVisible(true);
                }

            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class DebugBox extends JTextPane {

        private JScrollPane ScrollPane = null;
        private final JPopupMenu Menu = new JPopupMenu();
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7731036968185936516L;

        public DebugBox(int Width, int Height) {
            this.ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Width, Height));

            JCheckBoxMenuItem Debug = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -336209978671944858L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                 //DO something here that affects ALL the DebugBoxes because they all share this Menu Option somehow :S
                                 //Change name of this menu option, all instances have their names changed too.
                }
            });

            JMenuItem Copy = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6774461986513304498L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DebugBox.this.copy();
                }
            });

            JMenuItem Clear = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -5567371173360543484L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DebugBox.this.setText(null);
                }
            });

            JMenuItem SelectAll = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -8792250195980016624L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    DebugBox.this.selectAll();
                }
            });

            this.Menu.add(Copy);
            this.Menu.add(Clear);
            this.Menu.add(SelectAll);
            this.Menu.add(Debug);

            Copy.setText("Copy");
            Clear.setText("Clear");
            SelectAll.setText("Select All");
            Debug.setText("Show Debug Box");
            this.setEditable(false);
            this.add(this.Menu);

            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                        DebugBox.this.Menu.show(DebugBox.this, e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) how your work flow...

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620601/cant-a-swing-component-be-added-to-multiple-containers. Could you please show how you are handling the popup menu as per @MadProgrammer

Comment: Finished writing a quick and dirty SSCCE. I just edited the post.

Comment: Use standard Java naming conventions if you want other people to read your code. Variable names should not start with an upper case character.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm sorry. I program in C, C++, ASM, and all the others. It's hard to just "switch" conventions when so many other languages use a completely different convention from Java. I'll try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share an Object then you need to create the Object and pass the Object as a parameter to your other classes. Something like:

```
JPopupMenu popup = createSharedPopupMenu();
Pane.addTab("TabOne", M.new DebugBox(500, 500, popup));
Pane.addTab("TabTwo", M.new DebugBox(500, 500, popup));
```

Then you need to create generic Actions that will work on any text component. The DefaultEditorKit provides some of these Actions for you:

```
public JPopupMenu createSharedPopupMenu()
{
    JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu()

    JMenuItem copy = new JMenuItem( new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction() );
    popup.add( copy );
    ...

    return popup.
}
```

If the editor kit doesn't provide an Action for you then you need to create your own and you should extend `TextAction` instead of AbstractAction. The TextAction class has a method that will return the text component that has focus. So you can implement the Action in a generic way.

Also you don't need to use a MouseListener to invoke the popup. You can just use the following JComponent method:

```
JComponent.setComponentPopupMenu(JPopupMenu popup)
```

Comment: I will definitely check out the TextAction instead. I can't pass the Object as a parameter because the Object can only be contained by one container at a time. When added to a second container, it gets removed from the first. :(

Comment: That is correct, but a popupmenu is only ever displayed on one component at a time. It is not added to the Container on a permanent basis. All you are passing is a reference to the component so the popup can be shown/hidden as required.

Comment: Best answer! I did not think about that. At first I made a static final PopUpMenu and added a listener to each JTextArea but this answer is the best. I'm going to re-write it to suit this answer.