# Java Card Layout. One component in multiple cards

Tags: java, swing, awt, cardlayout

Can one component (e.g. a `JLabel`) be in multiple cards using `CardLayout`?

Currently it seems that the component appears only at the last card it was added to.

If there is a way to do this, should I? Is it bad practice? Or is there some alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't a Swing component be added to multiple containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620601/cant-a-swing-component-be-added-to-multiple-containers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that it only appears in the "last card it was added to", but that has nothing to do with `CardLayout`, that has to do with the fact each component can only be in one parent.

From the Javadoc for [`java.awt.Container.addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29):

> If the component is not an ancestor of this container and has a non-null parent, it is removed from its current parent before it is added to this container.

Comment: Okay... I guess I could create a component for each container but I don't really see the point. The label is used for displaying errors. Or should I create one label for one card and then work out which one is used and display that one?

Comment: @Bebras why not have the `errorLabel` be in the parent panel?

Comment: You mean to add it to the same one which contains my cards?

Comment: But won't it make it a card aswell?  And where exactly will it appear? Because in different cards it's in different positions

Comment: Sorry, I meant the parent container of the `CardLayout` formatted `JPanel`, and then it would appear next to the cards. But if you need it to be in different positions, I would use a separate `JLabel`, yes.