# Display of zoomed image in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, heatmap, joptionpane

I am making a `Java GUI` application, wherein a JPanel displays a `HeatMap` using the `HeatMap` Java class. When a user right clicks on this JPanel, a `popup menu` is displayed. Within this, the first option is to View the zoomed heatmap in a separate window. On clicking this option a new window should open providing a bigger image of the actual `HeatMap`. I am using the following code to perform this:

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new GUIMain(), getPanel(), "Zoomed heat map", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

`getPanel()` is a method that returns a panel containing the heatmap.

```
private JPanel getPanel() {
        JPanel zoomedImagePanel = new JPanel();
        zoomedImagePanel.add(getHeatMap());
        zoomedImagePanel.repaint();
        zoomedImagePanel.revalidate();
        return zoomedImagePanel;
    }
```

With the above code, I get a very small `HeatMap` in a new window and the `HeatMap` from the main `JPanel` disappears completely. 
Is using JOptionPane the wrong way to display the zoomed image? Also, not sure why the `HeatMap` from the main `JPanel` in the parent window disappears.

Comment: You can't add the same component to multiple panels http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620601/cant-a-swing-component-be-added-to-multiple-containers that is probably why the `HeatMap` disappears from the main `JPanel`.

Comment: What is `HeatMap`? It's not a standard class of Java (at least I cannot find it in SDK). Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I am using the `HeatMap` class by https://www.mbeckler.org/heatMap/

Comment: @Titus I read the post. I think it is applicable to Swing components and not objects like `HeatMap`. Please correct me if wrong. I my current code I am adding the same 'HeatMap` object in two different JPanels.

Comment: @novicegeek If you can do this `zoomedImagePanel.add(getHeatMap());` it means that the `HeatMap` class extends the `Component` class.