# JMenuItem reuse

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

Here is the minimal working application :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class JMenuItemReuse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestFrame::new);
    }
}

class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        super();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JPopupMenu menu1 = new JPopupMenu();
        JPopupMenu menu2 = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("reused");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("not reused");

        menu1.add(item1);
        menu2.add(item1); // works if this line is commented
        menu2.add(item2);

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                    menu1.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
                } else {
                    menu2.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(new JLabel("popup-test"));
        add(panel);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the popup menus do not work as expected when at least one menu item is reused. It is not a big issue, can be easily avoided by duplicating the reused menu item, but I am still wondering why does it happen. Any ideas?

Comment: `JMenuItem` is a `JComponent`.  A `JComponent` can only have one parent container. It's a limitation of Swing. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620601/cant-a-swing-component-be-added-to-multiple-containers

Comment: thanks for your comment

Comment: Don't re-use JMenuItems. Instead reuse **Actions** such as AbstractActions that you set the JMenuItem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JMenuItem` belongs to one, and only one, `JPopupMenu` (or any other menu). You cannot add a Swing component to more than one container; if you do, then the component will automatically be removed from the previous container.
Actaully if you want, you can create `Actions`. Actions can be shared and added to multiple components (JMenuItems, JButtons etc). You can even enable/disable the Action which will enable/disable all the components at the same time.